# Empirical means in the weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, random-variables, means, law-of-large-numbers

I'd like to know why in the weak low of large number we talk about empirical means (plural) $\overline{X}_n$ (I'm considering a series of $n$ random variables $X_i$).
Are we using the plural because we can define a mean for each random variable or for other reasons?

If possible write the formulas of at least two means in order to understand the differences between them.

Comment: One common example is the [truncated (trimmed) mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean).

Answer (score 0):

I guess we just use the plural to emphasize that we consider a sequence of means, indexed by $n$.